# Windows command-line: Is it possible to modify (or create) an scheduled task for "Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed"?

Tags: windows, command-line, scheduled-tasks

I wanna change this option via command line using **`schtasks`** (or whatever), but the docs seems not to have an option for it:

> Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed

only the GUI seems to allow it:

[image: Option to change - run ASAP]

I could workaround it too by creating a new task, if modification is not possible.

Comment: Task settings are saved here: "C:\Windows\System32\Tasks". The files are XML-based so if there was no other way at all, I would modify that file directly. There are many tools to modify XML files from command prompt like http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/ .

Comment: Not a bad idea, @ScottRhee. And, including in Windows something like GREP or any other simple Linux tool, the change could be made by just a command line.

Comment: @ScottRhee, the idea is good and easy (something like awk combined with grep from UnxUtils could do it), but... wouldn't that kind of change while Windows is running bring any kind of unstability to the system?

Comment: Sopalajo, I would stop the scheduler service before modifying it and then start the service back.